# returning the position of an element continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an object which is animated and falling from the top of the window to the bottom of the window. this works fine, but I would like to return the position of the element continuously.

At the moment I have this code

```
var pos = function() {
    console.debug(jQuery('.element').position());
}
jQuery(window).on('mousemove', pos);
```

Which returns the position of the class "element" when the mouse is moving, I have also tried the event handler "live" but it is not working.

Is there any event handler I can use which will continuously return the position of them elemnt? 
Thank you

Comment: How is the element animated, with CSS or jQuery? jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) has a `progress` callback function called after each step of the animation.

Comment: I am using animate()

Answer (score 2):

Use `.animate()`'s `step` callback to track whatever you want, from position to timing:

```js
var $test = $("span");
$("#element").animate({ top: 300 }, { 
  duration: 5000, 
  step: function(now, fx) { 
    $test.text( now );
  }
});
```

```css
#element{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  background:red;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span> px
<div id="element"></div>
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

---

A small suggestion, if you don't want to lose your fingers writing `jQuery` all over the place....

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready and jQuery $ alias secured

    // Free to use $ as you usually would

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval` to execute a function at given interval.

```
setInterval(function () {
    // do something here
}, 1000); // each 1 sec, starts after 1s
```